# Arduino Audio Shield Problems

Tags: shields, audio

I recently bought a Velleman KA02 Arduino Audio Shield (http://www.velleman.co.uk/contents/en-uk/p579_ka02.html), which uses an ISD1760PY audio chip and soldered it together. The first time I fired it up, it worked fine, I had freshly soldered it together. But from the next time up to now, if I press any button but the reset button, the onboard LED blinks 7 times and it doesn't record or do anything. I checked the solder joints and nothing fell out and I also checked the ISD1760PY datasheet but found nothing about my problem. Is there a way to fix this and why it it happening? Please note that I am not controlling the shield with SPI or with the Arduino.

This question was put on hold in the EE section so I an posting it here because the reason was that it has something to do with Arduino.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at page 35 of winbond datasheet.
If the LED is blinking 7 times either the chip is in isp mode or in an unstated mode. This can happen after power off during erase function.
I held erase button for about 20 seconds and after that I was able to record messages.